# jQuery DataTables rowreordering and CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, datatables

I'm using datatables on a Rails site and intend to make use of its' row reordering plugin. The documentation on the datatables site says implementation is easy - all I need to do is;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#example').dataTable()
      .rowReordering();
});
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to accomplish this with CoffeeScript, or if this is even necessary. My current ds.js.coffee file looks like this;

```
jQuery ->

  $('#thetable').dataTable
    bDestroy: true,
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    bAutoWidth: false,
    aLengthMenu: [[25,50,100,-1],[25,50,100,"All"]],
    iDisplayLength: 50,
    aoColumns: [{ "bSortable": false }, null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
    aaSorting: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    bStateSave: true;

  $(document).ready ->
    $('#thetable').dataTable
      .rowReordering();
```

But after managing this there's no drag and drop on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a function call:

```
$('#thetable').dataTable # <----------------
  .rowReordering();
```

The function-calling parentheses are **not** optional when you're calling a function without arguments (and various other places), you need to say:

```
$('#thetable').dataTable().rowReordering()
```

or

```
$('#thetable').dataTable()
  .rowReordering();
```

Comment: Yes, I should've spotted that. Thanks. However this is not the only issue preventing the re-ordering. I have it now and I believe that jqueryui was not being included. Additionally there was some more configuration of the datatable required - it's not as simple as the documentation makes out.

Comment: @ObregonCornsnook: The documentation tends to present a simplified version of reality :)